# Send Woocommerce email on custom action not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to send a custom email when a post is published using the Woocommerce email template.

I have included the template and class which Woocommerce loads using the `woocommerce_email_classes` and have also registered the custom action `send_entry_list` in the `woocommerce_email_actions` filter.

```
do_action('send_entry_list', $competition_id, $entry_list_url);
```

When adding `add_action` to this within the `class-entry-list-email.php` which triggers the email, it's not printing out '`triggered`' in the debug.log file.

Does anyone know why this isn't firing?

```
public function __construct() {
   add_action( 'send_entry_list', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
}

public function trigger( $competition_id, $entry_list_url ) {
    error_log(print_r('triggered', true));
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', array($this, 'add_draw_number_email'));

function add_draw_number_email( $email_classes ) {
    // include our custom email class
    require( 'includes/class-entry-list-email.php' );

    // add the email class to the list of email classes that WooCommerce loads
    $email_classes['Entry_List_Email'] = new Entry_List_Email();

    return $email_classes;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', array($this, 'crwc_register_custom_order_status_action'));


function crwc_register_custom_order_status_action( $actions ) {

    $actions[] = 'send_entry_list';

    return $actions;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you are missing `_notification` in the `add_action` hook. In WooCommerce email, you need to add `_notification` in the `tag` name of `do_action`.

In your case, you are using `send_entry_list` in both `do_action` and `add_action` whereas in `add_action` you just need to append `_notification` in the `tag` name so hook name becomes `send_entry_list_notification`.

To make this easy for you just do the following change.

Replace this line:

```
add_action( 'send_entry_list', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
```

with this:

```
add_action( 'send_entry_list_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
```

Hope, it works for you.

Comment: Hi Sami, this works! How come by adding  in _notification to the end makes this work?

Answer (score 0):

Change hook as below and try,

`add_action( 'send_entry_list', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );`

Comment: Hi Jaydip, I tried adding in what you suggested but it's still not firing